# First row displaying 0 for cellFilter applied fields in ui-grid grouping

Tags: angularjs

Please find the plunker link: https://embed.plnkr.co/LDJ5JyuVhGaXIoBn3nW8/ . There is a 0 appearing on the first row for the field(age) to which I have applied the filter.I doubt it is because of the logic in the filter.Am new to ui-grid implementation so any help and suggestion would be helpful!

Comment: There's no way anyone can answer such a question - please include a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hi Nino, I would try to provide a plunker by reproducing the issue. I have attached an image for reference which appears on "enter image description here".

Comment: The image doesn't show any code, please indeed edit the question so as to include a plunker

Comment: Please find the plunker link: http://embed.plnkr.co/LDJ5JyuVhGaXIoBn3nW8/

There is a 0 appearing on the first row for the field(age) I have applied the filter.I doubt it is because of the logic in the filter.Any help and suggestion would be helpful!

Comment: Please edit your question instead of adding comments

Answer (score 0):

In the plunker change the age column definition like below

```
{
    name: 'age',
    cellFilter: 'gbConversion',
    treeAggregationType: uiGridGroupingConstants.aggregation.MAX,
     customTreeAggregationFinalizerFn: function(aggregation) {
      aggregation.rendered = aggregation.value;
    },
    width: '20%',
    type: 'number'
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But I don't want any value in that row. The Max value is also not needed.

Comment: Then you can simply remove it you will not see zero's in the first row

Comment: Thank you Ali, the 0 was because of my filter. I have include the if condition as below and it worked.

       return function (bytes) {
            if(bytes){
                if (isNaN(bytes))
                    bytes = 0;
                bytes /= 1073741824;
                if (bytes < 0.01) {
                    return 0;
                }
                if (bytes > 0 && bytes < 1) {
                    return bytes.toFixed(2);
                }
                return bytes.toFixed(0);
            }
            else{
                return bytes;

            }